# How do I install PHP on an Earthlink Linux server?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

My ultimate, simple goal, is to install Wordpress.

Unfortunately, Wordpress requires PHP 5.2.4 or greater, while the server my site is hosted on is only running 5.2.17. When I contacted Earthlink, they said they couldn't update it, but that I could.

However, after a little bit of searching, I'm not sure where to begin. I have very little command line experience, and no Linux experience. I'm not even sure what flavor of Linux they're using. Does anyone know of any walkthrough guides or tutorials?

The odd thing is, Earthlink has a Wordpress installer built in to their control center (I'm opting for an FTP install, because I want to install in a subdomain). So alternatively, can I get away with installing on the server with PHP 5.2.17? If they're doing it, why can't I?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: How is 5.2.4 > 5.2.17?

Comment: Get a new host. This type of question should have been answered by their tech support in minutes.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the PHP version numbering system. `5.2.4` can be understood as the fourth versioned release of the major **5.2** version, while `5.2.17` is the seventeenth versioned release of the major **5.2** version. You should be good to go already.

Comment: use "yum install php": http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/php-linux-install-php-upgrade-howto/

Comment: I didn't try it because—for all I know—it may have appeared fine, but could have cause problems later. I thought it best to ask experienced people first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you understand PHP versions.  PHP 5.2.17 is a newer version than 5.2.4.  Wordpress should work just fine on 5.2.17.  Have you run into issues while installing it?

Comment: Thanks to all. Yes, I misunderstood the version numbering system. And I would love to get a new host, but it's not my call, unfortunately.